# Is it possible to write a C program on Windows for Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, virtualbox

I'm creating a linux shell, and i've been developing it on a VirtualBox virtual machine of linux on my windows 10 pc. Recently I've upgraded to Windows 11 and for some reason that makes the vm run at unbearably slow speeds. Therefore i how to comply and not use the linux vm, so i need to develop the shell in windows and execute it using WSL2 or any other command line. Is it possibly to use the linux libraries (e.g : <unistd.h>) on Windows?

Comment: WSL2 + VSCode + CMake = Love. Can't recommend it highly enough.

Comment: The point of WSL2 is that you can run actual Linux binaries, including compilers and development tools.  So yes, you should be able to develop and test your shell with WSL2 and then later ship the binaries or source code to be used on a real Linux system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you [setup WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), you should be able to develop C like you did on your VirtualBox machine. If decide to use Ubuntu, running `sudo apt-get install build-essential` should give you everything you need to compile and run C programs.

Comment: thank you very much, this actually works. Also for anyone trying to do the same , make sure you c file is **in** the wsl filesystem , otherwise it won't work.

Comment: small problem when i run `buf=getlogin();` it comes out as null , but when tested on the linux vm it works fine , do you happen to know a fix for this too? If it helps i think it's a problem with logging logins (Im not a linux guru) , because the command `last` never returns a login on wsl it only prints `wtmp begins Fri Dec 31 22:41:00 2021`

Comment: @Ledrake confirm `getlogin` fails (dunno why) but `getpwuid(getuid)` works

Answer (score 1):

It's called cross compiling. Using WSL(2) is kind of "overkill" for just building applications, but it makes testing the result a lot easier.

If all you're after is building, but not running the resulting executables, my suggestion would be MSys2 + LLVM + Clang. The nice thing about LLVM/Clang is, that it is always a "cross"-compiler; you can compile for every supported target on every supported host. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

There are also Linux targeting GCC builds available in MSys2, so that's an option, too.